# WooCommerce - Customer Order History Pagination

Tags: php, functions, pagination, woocommerce-offtopic, order

**I'm trying to implement pagination into WC's customer order history that can be seen on the "My Account" page using woo_pagination().**

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woo_pagination/

The template file I'm trying to edit is - woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php

By default the 15 most recent orders are shown. I have changed [woocommerce_my_account] page tag to [woocommerce_my_account order_count="all"] to display all orders instead of only the last 15.

What I'm trying to do now is add the woo_pagination function to display X orders per page so that an entire order history is available to customers in an organized way. But I'm not sure how to add it and I did not find the documentation very helpful in this case.

**Here's a copy of the template I'm trying to add the pagination function to:**

```
$my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
    'order-number'  => __( 'ID', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-date'    => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'   => __( 'Packages', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'   => __( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) );

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );

if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', __( 'Recent Orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">
    <?php echo $customer_orders['numberposts']. '<br>test'; ?>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                ?>
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                    $actions = array(
                                        'pay'    => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'view'   => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'cancel' => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                            'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                        )
                                    );

                                    if ( ! $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                        unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?> 
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried adding the pagination function after:

```
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but it did not work. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really, no ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have added pagination in order history page and it is working.
Replace below code above loop

`$my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
    'order-number'  => __( 'ID', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-date'    => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'   => __( 'Packages', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'   => __( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) )
$customer_orders1 = get_posts(apply_filters('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => wc_get_order_types('view-orders'),
    'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses())
        )));
$total_records = count($customer_orders1);
$posts_per_page = 20;
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $posts_per_page);
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$customer_orders = get_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => wc_get_order_types('view-orders'),
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses())
    ));`

and after loop completed add pagination

`<div class="pagination">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'base' => '%_%',
                'format' => '?page=%#%',
                'total' => $total_pages,
                'current' => $paged,
                'show_all' => False,
                'end_size' => 5,
                'mid_size' => 5,
                'prev_next' => True,
                'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
                'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
                'type' => 'plain',
                'add_args' => False,
                'add_fragment' => ''
            );
            echo paginate_links($args);
            ?>
        </div>`

Comment: On the latest version of WooCommerce, I had to change 2 things: 1. `'base' => @add_query_arg('?page', '%#%'),` and 2. `'format' => '?page=%#%'` - This was because when clicking page 1, this would just reload the 2nd page. A page 1 query wasn't working until I made this change.